# Spying on chained method calls with Jest not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I've made my own custom `TextInput` component that takes a `nextField` prop. When the "done" button in my `TextInput` is pressed, the `nextField` should be focused. Pretty simple. It works in production.

However, I'm having trouble testing the line of code that focuses `nextField`:

`this.props.nextField && this.props.nextField().focus()`

I'm testing it using this spy:

`const nextFieldSpy = jest.fn(() => {return {focus: jest.fn()}})`

It's my understanding that when the line of code under test is triggered, I should see that `nextFieldSpy` and `nextFieldSpy().focus` have both been called.

However, this is not the case. Here are the Jest expectations:

`expect(nextFieldSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`
`expect(nextFieldSpy().focus).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`

And this is the error I'm getting––the first line passes, but the second fails.

```
 Expected mock function to have been called one time, but it was called zero times.

  72 |     expect(nextFieldSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
> 73 |     expect(nextFieldSpy().focus).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`nextFieldSpy()` returns a new object every time it is called.

Change how you create `nextFieldSpy` to always return the same object:

```
const nextFieldResult = {focus: jest.fn()};
const nextFieldSpy = jest.fn(() => nextFieldResult);
```