# jest - spy function inside mock function

Tags: mocking, jestjs

I have a chained mock function inside another mock function, I need to spy both of them but I don't know how to spy the second one.

This is an example:

```
res = {
  status: jest.fn(() => {
    return {
      json: jest.fn()
    }
  })
}

expect(res.status).toBeCalled() // This works
expect(res.status.json).toBeCalled() // This does not
expect(res.status().json).toBeCalled() // This does neither
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution here: [Spying on chained method calls with Jest not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869381/spying-on-chained-method-calls-with-jest-not-working)

The trick is to separate definitions:

```
json = { json: jest.fn() }
res = {
  status: jest.fn(() => json)
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this has saved me a lot of time. Care to explain why this works though? What magic does storing the object to a variable do?

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-function-api#mockfnmockreturnthis

Like this:

```
const res = {
  status: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
  send: jest.fn()
};

// call function and pass res

expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledWith(200);
expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Something");
```

In app:

```
res.status(200).send("Something");
```